# Is there a better way of retriving Document Refernce?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore and I am developing an android app where I am loading comments in Recycler View.
Below is sample data class for comment.

```
data class Comment(
  val id: String,
  val text: String,
  val user: DocumentReference
)
```

Currently I am using this below code in `onBindViewHolder` in adapter

```
comment.userId.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener {
              if (it.isSuccessful) {
                val u = it.result.toObject(User::class.java)
                user = u.name
                binding.userTv.text = user
              }
            }
binding.commentTv.text = comment.text
```

I have to explicitally run `Task<TResult>` every time to fetch the user in adapter.
I am looking for a better way to retrieve user from comment to display `username` is a single query.

Comment: Well you have a list of comments, so you should fetch the users for all of those first, before you show the data. Ideally your adapter shouldn't be doing *any* non-ui related work.

Comment: @HenryTwist Agreed. Here I am using `FirestorePagingAdapter`. I am thinking of some generic approach or some solution within firebase api itself.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when dealing with usernames that may update regularly, traditionally you would store the raw user name string in each document which requires heavy read/writes to keep it updated. Instead, it has been found better to store them in a master document/collection that assigns all user UID's with the display name as the value, allowing you to look up any user UID and know it from one source of truth.

This has been made easier with the new Bundle Feature which allows all apps to preload documents in your app to prevent the need to fetch them every time. The only catch is you will need to retrieve the data when a new user isn't in their cached data yet or have a dedicated source for all new users to reduce overhead in those situations.

Source: [Data Bundles](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/04/firestore-supports-data-bundles.html)

Comment: This is such a pain. Tomorrow I have to count reactions on comment and perform sort operation. I have also used `FirestorePagingAdapter` for reduce paging efforts. I am thinking to migrate to a relational database.

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways to handle what you are after, Firestore, however, isn't designed as a social media database, it can be done by decentralizing your data with firestore and realtime, but its core processing is designed to be on the client.